# A right-continuous non-decreasing process is cadlag?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider a measureable process $A:\mathbb{R}_+\times \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $t\mapsto A_t$ is a right-continuous non-decreasing process.

Then is it true that $A$ is cadlag?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Which property of $A$ do you have to verify? Where are you stuck?

Comment: You need to show only that a non-decreasing function has limits a gauche. Consider $g(t) = \sup\limits_{s \leq t} h(s)$ and show $\lim\limits_{s \to t^-} h(s) = g(t).$

Comment: @WillM. Thanks. All the processes I've learned were a priori cadlag. I can't think of a counter- example. Could you provide a counter-example?

Comment: I am telling you how you can show $A$ is cadlag. It is, so no counterexample.

Comment: @WillM. This would imply that all the right-continuous finite variation processes would be cadlag as well. Do you know any books that have related discussions? The books I read a priori assume the processes are cadlag.

Comment: I have read really little about stochastic processes, basically only four books: Markov Processes by Ethier & Kurtz, Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus by Karatzas & Shreve, Topics in Stochastic Processes by Ash & Gardner and Stochastic Calculus and Applications by Elliot.

Comment: @Amira A finite variation process is just the difference between two increasing processes. Any process which is finite variation is cadlag.